# WordPress menu is not displaying in the website but is visible in the console log and in the mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to develop my custom theme but I am having problem displaying menu.

I tried calling:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
) )
```

Instead of this `wp_nav_menu('primary')`
but, this did not solve my problem. The menu is working properly with other theme like `Twenty-nineteen` theme. There is no plugin added to my theme to check whether it is causing me the problem.

I have the following code to add menu in the `functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support('menus');


    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary', 'Footer Navigation');

}
add_action('init', 'my_theme_setup');
```

I am seeing the list of menus in console log and just a glimpse of menu list in mobile device which goes to be invisible afterwards. Where I am doing wrong? I am still stuck in this problem and I don't know what has gone wrong and what can I do to make it work.

Update: The menu on the mobile works perfectly. This is the website that I am working on. trainerjames.edu.np. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

did you hit the checkbox in wp admin menu where you can select for each menu the location?

Comment: @NicolajiFR Yes, I have.